# Friend function cannot access private member

Tags: c++, qt, private, friend-function

I want to access the private objects of the class `MainWindow` with the friend function `void recognized(RecoResult *result)` that has already another namespace `LapsAPI::RecoResult` in the parameter `result`. How can i access `Ui::MainWindow *ui` inside of this friend function?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "main.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    friend void recognized(RecoResult *result);
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "main.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // Iniciando classe de reconhecimento
    SREngine* en;
    en = new SREngine("clara.jconf");

    // Inicio do reconhecimento de voz
    en->setOnRecognizeAction(&recognized);
    en->startRecognition();

    printf("Ola!\n");
    printf("Reconhecendo\n");
    sleep(100);
    en->stopRecognition();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void recognized(RecoResult *result){
    if(result->getConfidence() > TRUST){
        cout << result->getUterrance() << " Confiança " << result->getConfidence() << endl;
        string uterrance = "";
        float confidence = 0.0;

        uterrance = result->getUterrance();
        confidence = result->getConfidence();

        cout << "MENSAGEM RECONHECIDA SEM FILTROS: " << uterrance << " " << confidence << "\n" << endl;
        ui->textBrowser->append("RECONHECIDA");
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
/home/dayannefernandes/GitHub/clara-interface/clara-ui/mainwindow.cpp:44: error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope
     ui->textBrowser->append("MENSAGEM RECONHECIDA");
     ^
```

Comment: Explain what you think `ui` should mean inside the `recognized` function

Comment: This has nothing to do with namespaces, `recognized` and `MainWindow` are both in the global namespace

Comment: Sorry i forget to tell about recognized, i cant chance the parameters because setOnRecognizeAction() need a LaPSAPI::RecoResult only, and i cant declare recognized inside MainWindow also because i'll have this error:
error: no matching function for call to 'LapsAPI::SREngine::setOnRecognizeAction(void (MainWindow::*)(LapsAPI::RecoResult*))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recognized` is a free function. Although you have given it access to the names of members of `MainWindow`, it is not a member of `MainWindow` and there are no `MainWindow` objects implicitly associated with the function.

Normally to fix this you would give another parameter to the function. However, since your function is being used as a callback function and it must have fixed signature, you can't do that here.

If you want the code inside `recognized` to be able to affect any objects , you will have to use global variables. For example you could have a global instance of `MainWindow`, or a global pointer which points to the instance currently invoking the `startRecognition` function  (and make sure you don't call this from multiple threads...)

(This is not a very good design in the LapsAPI but you can't change it so you have to work with it).

Comment: You got the problem, thanks haha! i cant declare or chance parameters , so i thought that a friend function would solve my problem of call a private object without chance LapsAPI, but i think i dont have another choice, since the software will be big and i may have problems in future with this... thks nway! :D

Answer (score -1):

`recognized()` is not a `MainWindow` method. You are not passing pointer or reference to `MainWindow` instance to `recognized()`. No wonder the  complier complains about undefined symbol.

Comment: Your answer should really suggest a solution

Comment: @M.M is right about the problem that would cause with a passing pointer, but thks for the answer !